# Finding inverse of $g(x) = \dfrac{3x + 1}{2x + g(x)}$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, inverse

Find $g^{-1}(3)$ given $g(x) = \dfrac{3x + 1}{2x + g(x)}$

My Approach:

\begin{align*}
y & = \frac{3x + 1}{2x + y}  &&  \text{(does $g(x)$ become $y$ also?)}\\
x & = \frac{3y + 1}{2y + x}  &&  \text{(I switched $x$ and $y$)}\\
\Rightarrow x(2y + x) & = 3y + 1\\                      
\Rightarrow  2xy + x^2 & = 3y + 1\\
\Rightarrow  2xy - 3y & = 1 - x^2\\
\Rightarrow  y(2x - 3) & = 1 - x^2\\
\Rightarrow y & = \frac{1 - x^2}{2x - 3}\\
\Rightarrow g^{-1}(x) & = \frac{1 - x^2}{2x - 3}\\
g^{-1}(3) & = \frac{1 - 9}{6 - 3} = -\frac{8}{3}
\end{align*}

Does this seem correct? If not any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated, I'm not friendly with the website syntax/latex

Comment: Double check your definition

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the question right? Since subtracting both sides by g(x) gives 0=3x + 1/2x for all x, which is just false.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $g(x)=\frac{3x+1}{2x+g(x)}$ instead? What you have written doesn't really make sense because the $g(x)$ terms will cancel from both sides.

Comment: Hi recheck my post, because I edited it to be more understandable

Comment: If you hit edit, you can see how I edited your post. I hope that helps you write or respond to questions in future.

Comment: Thanks Taussig I'll review this to understand more how to write in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct.

Note that $g^{-1}(3) = -\dfrac{8}{3} \Longleftrightarrow g\left(-\dfrac{8}{3}\right) = 3$.

As a check,
\begin{align*}
g\left(-\frac{8}{3}\right) & = \frac{3\left(-\frac{8}{3}\right) + 1}{2\left(-\frac{8}{3}\right) + g\left(-\frac{8}{3}\right)}\\
3 & = \frac{-8 + 1}{-\frac{16}{3}  + 3}\\
  & = \frac{-24 + 3}{-16 + 9}\\
  & = \frac{-21}{-7}\\
  & = 3
\end{align*}